# What does it mean $\int_1^\infty\frac{F(y)}{y^2}\mathrm dy$?

Tags: probability, integration

Which type of functions will satisfy this?

$$F: [1,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$$

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{F(y)}{y^2} dy \leq 1$$

Comment: What do you mean by 'satisfy this'? You can use any function as $F$! Do you want this integral to be finite or have a certain value?

Comment: I am reading a research paper there i find this statement.I want to know the meaning why the area under the curve should be <=1 and also which functions can satisfy?

Comment: So you want to know which functions $F$ satisfy $I(F) := \int_1^\infty F(y)/y^2 dy \leq 1$? Are there other restrictions on $F$? (e.g. is $F$ nonnegative? do you know that $I(F) \geq 0$?

Comment: Yes F is increasing right continuous function  F :[1,infinite)->[0,infinite)

Comment: Please refer to [the mathjax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for learning about how to use latex here.

Comment: For any function F(y) such that that integral converges to a positive value, one can simply divide that function by a large enough value if necessary to obtain a function satisfying the constraints... so there are a LOT of functions satisfying that constraint

Comment: I want to prove this inequality.For that i want to know which function?

Answer (score 1):

$I(F) := \int_1^\infty \frac{F(y)}{y^2} dy$

$F$ is nonnegative and we know that $\int_1^\infty \frac 1 {y^2} dy = 1 $.

So if $F(x) \leq 1 \forall x\geq 1$ then  $$I(F) \leq \int_1^{\infty} \frac{dy}{y^2} = 1.$$

Comment: $\int_1^\infty\frac1y\mathrm dy$ diverges. Did you mean $\int_1^\infty\frac1{y^2}\mathrm dy$?

Comment: Of course, thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please provide me some hints to prove this?

Comment: To prove what exactly?

Comment: I want to prove that integral from 1 to infinite is <=1

Comment: That is exactly what I did in my answer, what step is unclear?